# No action on submit button?

Tags: php, html, input, paypal

I am having problems with my submit button. It's supposed to take them to the Paypals payment page once clicked on but absolutely nothing happens when I click on it.

You can see it live here: http://cashski.com/buy-instagram-followers.php
Click on "View Pack" for the first pack and then on the green "Checkout" button.

Here is my HTML code for the button:

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
     <input type="hidden" name="business" value="kottish94@hotmail.com">
     <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
     <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="2 000 Instagram Followers">
     <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="9.00">
     <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Instagram Username" maxlength="200">
     <input type="text" name="os1" placeholder="Example: http://instagram.com/YOURUSERNAME" required>
     <input type="button" border="0" name="submit" value="Checkout" alt="Buy Instagram Followers">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use
 input type="submit"

instead of 
 input type="button" 
and Replace CSS TO Submit button instead of button. Your Problem will solve